# Is it possible to get all my chat ids in telegram bot api?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, telegram-api

I'm writing a bot that will send the same message for many people I've ever communicated in telegram. So I need to get all my old `chat_id`'s.
All I found is just to store `chat_id` when I receive a new message as here [Retrieve all chat ids using Telegram bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38686587/retrieve-all-chat-ids-using-telegram-bot)

But it doesn't fit me. If is it possible, please tell me, I'd really apreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible, as there is no such method listed in the [Bot API Docs](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api).